# Execute .ksh file in Unix

Tags: unix, ksh

I have folder called QC, Inside that I have created a very basic script like below

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

#--------------------------
# set program name
#--------------------------
PROGRAMNAME=Run_all_Qc

#Remove old output file
    rm dhqc_notify_msg.tmp
```

I created .ksh file out this say qc.ksh in same folder, I have checked permission for this .ksh script I do have -rwxr-xr-x & I executed like

```
./qc.ksh
```

I am getting this error

```
interpreter "/usr/bin/ksh" not found
sh: ./qc.ksh:  not found
```

I am new to Korn shell scripts, I am struggling to understand this error (I am using tool WRQ reflection for UNIX and open VMS to execute).

Comment: You don't have `ksh` installed. Figure out what package provides it (probably `ksh` or something similar) and install it.

Comment: Is your ksh maybe in `/bin/ksh`? If it is installed at all, you might try the big hammer `find / -name ksh` to find where.

Comment: I tried which ksh it gives "usr/bin/ksh" is that mean ksh installed?

Comment: Can you check the last character of the first line? When it is a space or `^M`, the interpreter gets stuck.

Comment: I checked for space it doesn't have, I just tried copy paste whole code in the terminal and entered it removed the file, when I try with ./qc.ksh it isn't working, I have the qc.ksh file in the same path where I have code

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/ksh -c 'echo "Echo works" ' `. Do you have rights to execute `/usr/bin/ksh`? Use `ps` and see what shell you are running now. Try `source qc.ksh`, that should work (it ignores the shebang). Or edit `qc.ksh` and deavtivate the shebang (remove it, enter a different line above it or remove the `!`).